# Google doesn't display the email menu

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Hy, I'm trying to make a login on firebase using google SignIn. My problem is that when i'm gooing to connect, the application doesn't show me the email menu with all the email available and it do the connection without give the possibility to set more than one account.

[image]

I post my code below:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Btn_Sign = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        GoogleSignInOptions SignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this, this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, SignInOptions).build();
         mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);


        Btn_Sign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });

    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CODE) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {

                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Intent start = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                            startActivity(start);
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
```

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have always the dialog showing you need to disconnect your user before sign in
You can do it with this code

```
GoogleSignIn.getClient(getActivity(), GoogleSignInUser.getGoogleSignInOptions(getActivity())).signOut()
                .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@android.support.annotation.NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        GoogleSignIn.getClient(getActivity(), GoogleSignInUser.getGoogleSignInOptions(getActivity())).revokeAccess()
                                .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        //do what you want
                                    }
                                })
                                .addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCanceled() {
                                        //do what you want
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                });
```